# Показать ProgressBar если грузится дольше чем X секунд

Tags: android

У меня есть AsyncTask который загружает данные с сервера. В onPreExecute() и onPostExecute() я показываю и убираю progressbar. Как сделать так, чтобы в progressbar показывался только если операция в AsyncTask выполняется дольше определенного времени?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `AsyncTask` есть метод `onProgressUpdatе`, в котором можно показать ProgressBar после N секунд с момента запуска задачи.

Для вызова этого метода, в методе `doInBackground` надо периодически вызывать метод `publishProgress`.

Чтобы посчитать, сколько секунд прошло с момента запуска задачи, надо в методе `onPreExecute` получить текущее время

```
startDate = new Date();
```

Затем, в методе onProgressUpdatе вычислять разницу между текущим временем и временем, когда была запущена задача

```
Date now = new Date();
long diffInSec = (now.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / 1000;
if (diffInSec > N_SECONDS) {                 //сюда можно добавить проверку на то, что ProgressBar еще не виден пользователю
    //показаться ProgressBar
}
```

[Подробнее об onProgressUpdatе и publishProgress на developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)